# What is the best method for painting a door

Tags: doors, painting, repainting

I'm planning to repaint a closet door to match a newly painted room. Would it be better to use spray paint or just use a brush and the same paint I'm using on the walls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither!  Your door should be painted the same color as the trim, which is usually in a glossier finish than the walls. Semi gloss or gloss is typical for trim and doors.

The best finish is achieved when you remove the door, lay it flat and paint it with a good soft bristle brush. If it is a raised panel style door, start by painting the inner most details first, inner stiles second and finish with the outer stiles. Finish with long strokes going in the same direction as the grain.  Painting the door while laying flat will help eleminate runs and sags in detail corners.  Good Luck.

Comment: was just about to post :) To add to shirlock holmes; a foam brush or foam roller will eliminate brush marks. the foam brush will help get paint into the corners of any panels on the door also. And I would highly suggest removing any old paint before hand from the door if possible.

Comment: If you don't want to brush, a 6" hot dog style roller with a 1/4 inch nap works as well.

Comment: a small roller is good for getting paint on fast, but a good finish without the "orange peel" looks requires a tip off with a good quality soft tapered brush.

Comment: @Shirlock - I totally agree.  The brush is a compromise on finish versus speed.  But when you got X doors to paint...Convincing wife to help paint door(s), hard.  Convincing wife to paint door(s) with brush, impossible.  The roller worked and we split the difference.